# Configure Windows 7 settings during/before installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, deployment

Is there a program that can be used to configure the settings within a Windows 7 ISO before installation? By settings I mean things like:

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization

Control Panel\System and Security

Control Panel\Network and Internet

I know some settings can be configured (UI language, creating partitions,  etc.) using the Windows Automated Installation kit (AIK) and creating a autounattend.xml file, but can all the settings be preconfigured or does one have to go through and configure each setting after the installation. I have come across the Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer (ICD) but that only seems to be for Windows 10. I know things like "God Mode" exist but that is still a tiresome way of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its called [sysprep by Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preparing-an-image-using-sysprep-and-imagex.aspx)

Comment: [There there is this program also](http://www.rt7lite.com/)

Comment: Yeah I have used rt7lite in the past, guess I will have to go down the sysprep route then.

Comment: Moad's spot on, SysPrep can do it all. Bit of a learning curve though. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744263(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about this:
After installing Windows you can use Shift+Ctrl+F3 to enter Audit Mode, make the customizations in question and Sysprep as described by Moab.
You can perform the customizations through an answer file and if needed, scripts. This is a little more complex to set up, but has the benefit of being repeatable.
You can also use a deployment solution like MDT or SCCM to automate the deployment, this is even more automated than using an answer file and is more easy to manage when you need to tweak or change the process.